# AWS CLI not working for VPN tunnel options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to use AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 modify-vpn-tunnel-options
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice.

But according to [modify-vpn-tunnel-options — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-vpn-tunnel-options.html) above should work.

I have searched everywhere on google can't find anything. Does anyone know if there is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your AWS CLI with:

```
pip install awscli --upgrade
```

I could reproduce your error on `aws-cli/1.16.114`, but it worked fine on `aws-cli/1.16.184`.